# How many screen resolutions are available for Windows 8 mobile app?

Tags: gui-design

I am a UX/UI designer and I have designed many mobile apps for iPhone and Android.
Now I have to design a mobile app for Windows 8 but I don't know how many screen resolutions are available. i.e. for iPhone there are two resolutions (320x480 & 640x960).

If anybody knows then please let me know.

Comment: this should be on http://www.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft supports a number of resolutions for Windows Phone 8:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206974(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Supportedresolutions

I advice you to take a similar approach as you would with Android. This because Android uses a much wider variety of resolutions than Apple. These variety of resolutions leads to a (more) fluid design where elements don't have fixed widths of heights. This approach also makes your app future prove: who knows what resolutions Microsoft is going to support in the future.

Apple actually has more resolutions for the iPhone since iPhone5 (1136 x 640). The 640x960 is the retina version of the 320x480. The higher resolution displays everything a lot sharper but is not really handled as a different resolution the way you're used to.